# Finding Dynamic Variable in a list VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find the value of a variable (MonthCell) in a different workbook. The variable I am trying to find is within a list. When I run the below code the Month variable remains empty, even though there should be a match. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub CreateAList()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim coll As Collection
Dim Hotel As Excel.Range
Dim arr() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim MyFiles As String, ThisMonth As String
Dim startPath As String
Dim WhereCell As Range
Dim Month As Range

Set ws = Application.Workbooks("Booking Pace - Test 
Tool.xlsm").Sheets("Forecast") startPath = 
"C:\Users\gborner\Documents\Projects\"

With ws
LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set coll = New Collection
For Each Hotel In .Range("A6:A" & LastRow)
    On Error Resume Next
    coll.Add cell.Value, CStr(cell.Value)
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set WhereCell = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A6:A200").Find(Hotel, 
    LookAt:=xlPart)
    Set MonthCell = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B3")

    MyFiles = Dir(startPath & "*" & Hotel & "*.*")

    'Do While MyFiles <> ""

        On Error Resume Next
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Workbooks.Open startPath & MyFiles

    Set Month = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Budget").Find(MonthCell, 
    LookIn:=xlValues)
```

Comment: You haven't defined `cell`. Do you mean `hotel`?

Comment: Which cell do you mean? I am trying to find the location of the MonthCell variable in another workbook and will offset from there

Comment: @Gabriela `coll.Add cell.Value, CStr(cell.Value)`

Comment: `coll.Add cell.Value, CStr(cell.Value)`. Your On Errors are just masking problems.

Comment: sorry for my dumb question, but how would i incorporate this into my code?

Comment: You should avoid using VBA commands as variables,i.e. `Month`

Comment: Incorporate what into your code?

Comment: coll.Add cell.Value, CStr(cell.Value)

Comment: @Gabriela It's *already* in your code, between `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0` - but you haven't assigned any value to `cell`, so it is `Nothing`.  Add the line [`Option Explicit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement) to the top of your module, then go "Debug" > "Compile VBA Project" in the menu.  **Then** go "Tools" > "Options" > "Require Variable Declaration" and never turn that setting off.  (Also, you seem to have some lines of code that are cut up funny, or squashed into each other)

Answer (score 1):

The below code loop all sheets and search for variable called SearchValue. At the end populate a message box with all relevant matches.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim SearchValue As String, FullReport As String
    Dim Position As Range

    SearchValue = "Test"

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        Set Position = ws.UsedRange.Find(SearchValue)

        If Not Position Is Nothing Then
            If FullReport = "" Then
                FullReport = "The word " & SearchValue & " appears in " & ws.Name & ", " & "Column " & Position.Column & " and row " & Position.Row & "."
            Else
                FullReport = FullReport & vbNewLine & "The word " & SearchValue & " appears in " & ws.Name & ", " & "Column " & Position.Column & " and row " & Position.Row & "."
            End If
        End If

    Next ws

    MsgBox FullReport

End Sub
```

**Results:**

[image]